# Получить название песни, играющей в настоящее время на android

Tags: android, media

Можно ли получить исполнителя и название песни, играющей в данный момент на Android? Я знаю, что для Android нужно использовать java, но получится ли это сделать с помощью python?

Comment: Есть "грязный хак": при проигрывании песни - её название отображается на экране. Можно его заскриншотить и распознать.

Answer (score 0):

Получится сделать с помощью питон - нужно включить микрофон на том компьютере, где выполняется питон,  и отправить кусок песни в  шазам.

[image: how shazam works]

Comment: Это понятно, а "по-чистом" это никак не провернуть?